# Simple question about conversions (new coder)

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a game and I have 2 image assets, ones name is "1" and the others name is "2".
I understand that the problem is that i cannot apply math to a type image but i'd like to change image "1" to image "2". The error is:

> syntax : Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Image'.

Code:

````
controller.A.onEvent(ControllerButtonEvent.Pressed, function () {
    for (let index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
        mySprite.y += -2.5
        pause(25)
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < 8; index++) {
        mySprite.y += 2.5
        pause(25)
    }
})
controller.left.onEvent(ControllerButtonEvent.Pressed, function () {
    var current = mySprite.image
    mySprite.setImage(mySprite.image - 1)

})
let mySprite: Sprite = null
scene.setBackgroundImage(assets.image`myImage`)
mySprite = sprites.create(assets.image`4`, SpriteKind.Player)
mySprite.setPosition(80, 109)
forever(function () {
    controller.moveSprite(mySprite)
})
```
mySprite.setImage(mySprite.image - 1)
```
````

Comment: You'll need to supply more than one line of code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, you have an `<img/>` tag with an image in it, and want to programmatiaclly change the image. What you should do in this case, is altering the source:

`mySprite.src = 'my/new/image.png';`
assuming that 'mySprite' is the `<img />` element.

Comment: Since the error isn't "`setImage` is not a function," we can be fairly sure the OP's `mySprite` is not an `HTMLImageElement`.

Comment: I don't know if this clears up any confusion but I'm changing the image of my sprite. My sprites name is "mySprite" and i'm changing the image of "mySprite".

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I suspect you're right... Although it's not clear enough what mySprite is supposed to be.

Comment: also im only 15 and just started coding lol

Comment: Oh, a sprite is just like a character... for a game. I'm just using a simple online coding website called "Microsoft MakeCode". I'm not doing any raw coding.

Comment: @ethanthecrappycoder I understand, but it's unclear what `mySprite` is to javascript. Is it an object, an image source string? Knowing this will make us understand better what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is an object.

Comment: Another way to put is is with the code mySprite.setImage(mySprite.image - 1) I'm changing the current image that mySprite is set to. Currently it is set to image "2" but with mySprite.setImage(mySprite.image - 1) I'm trying to change the current one by subtracting one but the problem is that I can't do any math to it unless it's an integer or something. Sorry for wasting you time btw.

Comment: I see now. You try to resolve an `Image` object with a number which doesn't work, because JS doesn't know how those correspond. You'll have to assign an id to your images yourself, e.g. `myImage = { id: 1, image: mySprite }` and then look at the `id` property to make JS understand which image you're trying to set.